# Use SeekBar in Listview item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-seekbar

I have a listview that has a custom adapter with a SeekBar. The view inflate fine, but when I touch the SeekBar and try to change the value, it does not responde the click, do nothing, how can I solve it?

list_itemx.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

my getView function inside the adapter

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
View view;
if (convertView == null){
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dispositivo_list_item, parent, false);
}else{
    view = convertView;
}

final int mPosition = position;
holder = new ViewHolder(view);
holder.progress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean b) {
        changeProgress(mPosition,value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
holder.name.setClickable(false);
holder.name.setFocusable(false);
holder.progress.setFocusable(false);

holder.mView.setClickable(false);
return view;
```

}

Edit: I found the solution. I had a notifyDataSetChanged in a function that I call inside the callback. That's what was blocking the SeekBar. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: add your code,please

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. In other words: my SeekBar is working nicely, the OnSeekBarChangeListener is firing (tested on an emulator running Android 7). Looks like by filling in the gaps in your code I got rid of the error. So if you still need help please post more code.